# How to compare date type with a timestamp saved in Firebase database?

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I have a saved student presence on Firebase. With this, I have a travel screen that when starting should filter the presence that has the same date as the trip. but when I give console.log () it doesn't print anything. How can I compare the Firebase date attribute (timestamp) to a date attribute?

```
this.presencaSubscription = this.viagemService.carregarAlunosPorDataConfirmacao(this.data).subscribe(dados => {
      this.presencas = dados;
      console.log(this.presencas)
```

In the service:

```
carregarAlunosPorDataConfirmacao(data: Date) {
    return this.firestore.collection<Presenca>('presenca', ref => ref.where('startTime', '==', data)).snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(dados => {
        return dados.map(snap => {
          const data = snap.payload.doc.data();
          const uid = snap.payload.doc.id;
          return { uid, ...data };
        })
      })
    )
  }
```

Comment: I answered with an educated guess below. If that doesn't help you solve the problem, update your question to make it easier for us to help, by including hard-coded values for all variables (mostly `data`), by showing a screenshot of a document that you'd expect to be returned (so that we can check `startTime`), and by removing the need for the `map` operations, and possibly even AngularFire (as I expect you'd have the same problem with the regular JavaScript SDK).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firestore stores [date/time values as timestamps](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types#data_types) with a microsecond precision. Unless you've taken care to store those values normalized to specific microsecond offset (which you unfortunately don't show in your question), it is unlikely that two `Date` values will be the exact same (which is needed for the `==` comparison to succeed).

The two most common approach of dealing with dates likes this are:

1. Store your timestamps as rounded down to a specific granularity. So if you need to select by date, you'd for example store timestamps at midnight (0:00.000) utc, and also compare against those. For start times, you'd typically round to the nearest exact minute/hour.
2. Use range comparisons to get the property documents, so select any documents with a `startTime` between `2019-09-28T09:00:00.000Z` and `2019-09-28T09:00:59.999Z`.